# RandomAccessFile - Chinese characters when reading

Tags: java, character-encoding, character, randomaccessfile

Field on file.dat are organized this way:

NAME SURNAME NAME SURNAME ...

I use this piace of code to write to the file:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(dir, "rw");

file.seek(file.length());
file.writeChars(setField(this.name.getText()));
file.writeChars(setField(this.surname.getText()));
if (this.kind.equals("teachers")) {
  file.writeChars(setField(this.subject.getText()));
}

file.close();
```

And this for reading:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(path, "r");

int records = (int)file.length() / 60;

for (int i = 0; i < records; i++) {
    file.seek(file.getFilePointer() + 15);
    if (getContent(file).equals(surname[1])) {
        file.seek(file.getFilePointer() - 15);
        this.name.setText(getContent(file));
        this.surname.setText(getContent(file));
        break;
    }
}

file.close();
```

The getContent() functions:

```
private String getContent(RandomAccessFile file) throws IOException {
  char content[] = new char[15];

  for (short i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
     content[i] = file.readChar();
  }
  return String.copyValueOf(content).trim();
}
```

When reading from the file and setting the JTextField value, it display Chinese characters.
Why?

Comment: Seeing my question now, after eight years, I feel dumb hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`file.writeChars`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeChars%28java.lang.String%29) writes each `char` to the file as two bytes. Similarly, [`file.readChar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readChar%28%29) reads two bytes from the file and interprets them as a `char`. Keep this in mind whenever you move the file pointer.

For instance, if you want to skip 15 `char`s, you'll have to move the file pointer forwards by 30 bytes, like this: `file.seek(file.getFilePointer() + 30)`. It looks like this is what you're doing wrong.